# maven dependancy lookup fails even if I have specified repo

Tags: maven

I am trying to run a project. Its not able to find a dependency. So I have added repository inside pom.xml

But its not able to lookup for the same.

from pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>

        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <id>spring</id>
        <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

> 81749 [WARNING] Unable to create Maven project for
>   com.gemstone.gemfire:gemfire:pom:8.1.0 from repository.
>   org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Error resolving
>   project artifact: Failure to find
>   com.gemstone.gemfire:gemfire:pom:8.1.0 in
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced for project
>   com.gemstone.gemfire:gemfire:pom:8.1.0

when i applied -X i see following

```
103850 [DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
103850 [DEBUG] Project:       xxxxx:xxxxxx:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
103850 [DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): [compile+runtime]
103850 [DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile, compile+runtime, runtime, test]
103850 [DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
103850 [DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
```

What am I missing here ? I have parent pom.xml with repository mention

parent is not included in child

Comment: The above repository which you have defined does not really make sense, cause all of those artifacts are already in Maven central. The problem you have is that the given dependency `com:gemstone.gemfire` is not in Maven central...only here: https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gemfire

Comment: its not only this....example spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-server that too is not there in maven central

Comment: Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find javax-inject:javax-inject:pom:1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

and many more

Comment: Than it sounds more like a network issue firewall/proxy problem.....

Comment: @khmarbaise no...if I make this repository as 'central' maven site plug in fails....how do I check if maven is looking in both repository....central and one that I have specified....to me it seems it only looks 'central'

Comment: First you should define supplemental repositories in your settings.xml file and not in a pom file...maybe it's time to use a repository manager...

Comment:  this build is on a shared ci server. Let me check if I can do something....but my question...why it's not looking into repo inside pom.xml...how can I investigate that...do you know ?

Answer (score 1):

Given this pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gemstone.gemfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gemfire</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I tried to run:

```
$mvn clean compile
```

The result was:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/gemstone/gemfire/gemfire/8.1.0/gemfire-8.1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.gemstone.gemfire:gemfire:jar:8.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/gemstone/gemfire/gemfire/8.1.0/gemfire-8.1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.642 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-02T13:31:34+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/131M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for project test:test:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.gemstone.gemfire:gemfire:jar:8.1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

So I researched for the dependency and repository in mvnrepository.com and I found the repositories that contains this dependency are Spring Plugins and Spring Libs:

[image]

Then I just added the Spring Plugins repository in my pom and it worked!

The final POM is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gemstone.gemfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gemfire</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the same...But it didnt work either. this time, artifact is present in repo. I added more details with pom here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281165/unable-to-run-maven-build-on-gitlab-dependacy-missing-but-present-in-maven-centr

Comment: Thanks. I got it working this way, too. BUT: What do I want it to work? What is this plugin and do I want it? I only know that the error only happens when generating site reports and that I don't really need this plugin when I run my application. It only appears in the dependency-management page of my site reports and it doesn't even have a license.