# unable to run maven build on gitlab dependacy missing but present in maven central

Tags: maven, gitlab

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.domain.testapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>config</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <repositories>

        <repository>

            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>spring</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>

            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>spring-plugin</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR7</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>config</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am getting following error

```
96088 [DEBUG] Writing tracking file /builds/jigarshah/testapp/.m2/repository/javax-inject/javax-inject/1/javax-inject-1.pom.lastUpdated
96089 [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo1.maven.org/maven2
96089 [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo1.maven.org/maven2
96099 [DEBUG] Writing tracking file /builds/jigarshah/testapp/.m2/repository/javax-inject/javax-inject/1/javax-inject-1.pom.lastUpdated
96100 [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release
96100 [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release
96507 [DEBUG] Writing tracking file /builds/jigarshah/testapp/.m2/repository/javax-inject/javax-inject/1/javax-inject-1.pom.lastUpdated
96514 [DEBUG] Skipped remote request for javax-inject:javax-inject:pom:1, already updated during this session.
96515 [DEBUG] Skipped remote request for javax-inject:javax-inject:pom:1, already updated during this session.
96515 [DEBUG] Skipped remote request for javax-inject:javax-inject:pom:1, already updated during this session.
96516 [WARNING] Unable to create Maven project for javax-inject:javax-inject:pom:1 from repository.
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Error resolving project artifact: Failure to find javax-inject:javax-inject:pom:1 in https://repo.spring.io/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring has elapsed or updates are forced for project javax-inject:javax-inject:pom:1
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
```

I can see artifact is there on maven central

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/

Why its not resolving ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your proxy is set correctly in your settings.xml (it is if you can download other stuff from maven central), then you need to remove the local version and force it to download again from maven central.

I suggest :

1) Delete any local copy in your home drectory .m2/repo/javax/inject/javax.inject

2) do a mvn clean install -U to force and update.